# How can I limit my data.length with invariant data sizes so I don't ever get past the lastindex?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two list components or card stacks. 5 Decks and several cards in each deck. I am listing the 5 decks and passing it's content to a child component when I click on it with a (selectedItem) state. Then I'm picking that up in its child component and mapping another flatlist with the cards inside.

My problem is, when I click to an index that is beyond the limit of a smaller deck. For example,

```
Deck1 = 23 cards
Deck2 = 15 cards
```

When I index+1 on Deck1 to anywhere past 15, and I try to click on Deck2, it says it's out of range (obviously lol), I'd like it to reset to index(0) when I change decks. I can't just add more cards and make them all the same amount because I am setting a new feature later where the user can build his own deck and it can be any number of cards

Here's my Decks Component

```
const Decks = () => {
  const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext)
  let activeColors = colors[theme.mode]

  const allbelts = [yellowbelt, orangebelt, greenbelt, brownbeltthree, brownbelttwo, brownbeltone]

  const ref = useRef(null);
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState(null);
  const [deckIndex, setDeckIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleItemPress = (item) => {
    setSelectedItem(item);
    console.log("deckIndex:", deckIndex);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <View style={{flex:1, marginTop: 40}}>
        <Text style={[{color:activeColors.primary}, styles.sectionheading]}>
          Testing Card Decks
        </Text>
          <Animated.FlatList
            ref={ref}
            data={allbelts}
            horizontal
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            snapToInterval={ITEM_SIZE}
            decelerationRate={0}
            bounces={false}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            renderItem={({item, deckIndex}) => (
              <View 
                style={{}}>
                <TouchableOpacity 
                  key={deckIndex}
                  onPress={() => {
                    handleItemPress(item)
                  }}>    
                  <Animated.View 
                    style={[{
                      backgroundColor: item.color,
                      shadowColor: item.color,
                      borderColor: activeColors.bgalt}, 
                      styles.card]}>
                      <Text 
                        numberOfLines={2} 
                        style={[{color: item.color === "#F5D143" ? activeColors.black : activeColors.white}, styles.cardtitle]}>
                        {item.rank_japanese}
                      </Text>
                      <Text 
                        numberOfLines={2} 
                        style={[{color: item.color === "#F5D143" ? activeColors.black : activeColors.white}, styles.cardtitle]}>
                        {item.rank_english}
                      </Text>
                  </Animated.View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            )}
          />   
        <Cards selectedItem={selectedItem} deckIndex={deckIndex}  />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Decks
```

and here is the Cards component

```
const Card = ({info}) => {
  const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext)
  let activeColors = colors[theme.mode]

  const rotate = useSharedValue(0);
  
  const frontAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const rotateValue = interpolate(
      rotate.value, 
      [0, 1], 
      [0, 180]
    );
    return {
      transform: [
        {rotateY: withTiming(`${rotateValue}deg`, {duration: 500})}
      ]
    }
  })

  const backAnimatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    const rotateValue = interpolate(
      rotate.value, 
      [0, 1], 
      [180, 360]
    );
    return {
      transform: [
        {rotateY: withTiming(`${rotateValue}deg`, {duration: 500})}
      ]
    }
  })
  return (
    <View style={[styles.cardcontainer]}>
      <View style={styles.iconcnt}>
        <Pressable 
          onPress={() => {
            rotate.value = rotate.value ? 0 : 1;  
          }} 
          style={styles.icon}>
          <Icon name="swap-horizontal" size={24} color={activeColors.textcolor} />
        </Pressable>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.cardContent}>
        <Animated.View style={[ {backgroundColor: activeColors.bgalt, position:"absolute"}, styles.card, frontAnimatedStyle]}>
          <View>
            <Text 
              style={[{color: activeColors.textcolor}, styles.cardtext]}>
              {info.q}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </Animated.View>

        <Animated.View style={[ {backgroundColor: activeColors.primary}, styles.card, backAnimatedStyle]}>
          <View>
            <Text 
              style={[{color: activeColors.textcolor}, styles.cardtext]}>
              {info.a}
            </Text>
          </View>          
        </Animated.View>
      </View>
    </View>
    
  )
}

const Cards = ({selectedItem, deckIndex}) => {
  const {theme} = useContext(ThemeContext)
  let activeColors = colors[theme.mode]

  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [lastIndex, setLastIndex] = useState(null);
  const [viewPosition, setViewPosition] = useState(0.5);

  const flatlistRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setLastIndex(selectedItem?.questions?.length - 1);

    // console.log("selectedItem:", selectedItem);
    console.log("lastIndex at TestingCards:", lastIndex);

    flatlistRef.current?.scrollToIndex({
      index: index, 
      animated: true,
      viewPosition,
    })
  } , [index, viewPosition, lastIndex, selectedItem])

  if (!selectedItem) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <View style={[styles.container]}>
      <Animated.FlatList
        data={selectedItem.questions}   
        ref={flatlistRef}
        index={deckIndex}           
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        initialScrollIndex={0}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        snapToInterval="ITEM_SIZE"
        decelerationRate={0}
        bounces={false}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        initialNumToRender={10} 
        onScrollToIndexFailed={index => {
            setIndex(0) 
          const wait = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
          wait.then(() => {
            flatlistRef.current?.scrollToIndex({ index: index, animated: true });
          });
        }}
        renderItem={({item, index}) => <Card info={item} index={index} totalLength={lastIndex} seefront={true} />}
      />
      <View style={styles.btnGroup}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={()=>{
            setIndex(0);
            setViewPosition(0.5);
          }}>
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['rgba(1,102,175,1)', 'rgba(155,24,213,1)']}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
            style={styles.btnPrimary}>
            <Icon name="chevron-double-left" size={24} color={activeColors.white} />
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>      
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={()=>{
            if (index === 0) {
              return;
            }
            setIndex(index - 1);
            setViewPosition(0.5);
          }}>
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['rgba(1,102,175,1)', 'rgba(155,24,213,1)']}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
            style={styles.btnPrimary}>
            <Icon name="chevron-left" size={24} color={activeColors.white} />
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>               
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={()=>{
            if (index === lastIndex) {
              return;
            }
            setIndex(index + 1);
            setViewPosition(0.5);
          }}>
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['rgba(1,102,175,1)', 'rgba(155,24,213,1)']}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
            style={styles.btnPrimary}>
            <Icon name="chevron-right" size={24} color={activeColors.white} />
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>   
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={()=>{

            if (index === lastIndex) {
              return;
            }
            setIndex(lastIndex - 1);
            setViewPosition(0.5); 
          }}>
          <LinearGradient
            colors={['rgba(1,102,175,1)', 'rgba(155,24,213,1)']}
            start={{ x: 0, y: 1 }}
            end={{ x: 1, y: 1 }}
            style={styles.btnPrimary}>
            <Icon name="chevron-double-right" size={24} color={activeColors.white} />
          </LinearGradient>
        </TouchableOpacity>            
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default Cards
```

Comment: where is FlashCards used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
  flatlistRef.current?.scrollToIndex({
    index: index, 
    animated: true,
    viewPosition,
  })
} , [index])  
useEffect(()=>{
  setIndex(0)
  setLastIndex(selectedItem?.questions?.length - 1);
  setViewPosition(0.5)
}, [selectedItem])
```

It will reset index to 0 whenever deckIndex is changed, on the other hands whenever you choose different deck.
You may add some codes to reset other things inside useEffect.

Update:

```
initialNumToRender={selectedItem.questions.length}
```

It will be needed in FlatList to avoid scrollToIndex error.

Comment: That didnt do it. I wasn't sure which component this would be set in so I did it in the cards component which is where setIndex lives and it just toggled between the first two cards on the deck selected back and forth. Very strange. Then I tried it on the parent component and it didnt change anything

Comment: To answer your question above, the FlashCards component was renamed just while i was copying the code sorry. I edited my OP. Basically the Decks component is what fills the route. It takes in a Cards component and the Cards component renders a collection of Card component

Comment: Yes, it should be placed in cards component. I have updated useEffect condition.

Comment: Oooof it almost worked!!!! It did reset back to index0 when i changed decks, but the Error is catcing before it sets the index `Invariant Violation: scrollToIndex out of range: requested index 23 is out of 0 to 22`

Comment: actually no meaning of viewPosition and lastIndex because there is no change of viewPosition and no using of lastIndex. so you don't need to declare them as state.

Comment: Yeah it still doesn't work. I can click on another deck and it will revert to index0, but if the state is holding a higher index at than the one I'm clicking at the time, because I am asking for index + 1 it fails if it doesn't find it. Say for instance I came from index 23. when I call for index +1, it expects index24. I feel like I know this but can't quite get my code to do what's in my head

Comment: It would be needed to debug your code with actual data if you want your code worked completely. I hope you understand the way how to use useEffect hook and state.

Comment: I do, this is a racing condition. But I'll see if I can implement this on some sort of online editor

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@lotusms/deck I made this simplified version, but of course, my luck, scrolltoindex isn't supported in snack editor. Maybe you can make some sense of it. It's ok if you dont wanna trouble yourself

Comment: It would be best if it's possible to share the full code.

Comment: The fill code is in this question. I can't add it to the snack because it wont run due to other dependencies

Comment: Is there a repository uploaded on git?

Comment: yes. I can add you to it id you want. WHat's your github handle? I'll send the invite. I can't thank you enough man

Comment: I'll upgrade my question to a bounty and give you the answer so you get a bigger bump

Comment: GitHub id: jonasbeckdev

Comment: Invite Sent....

Comment: It runs on emulator. but I can't find appropriate components, no components named likely Decks and Card.

Comment: I just merged my latest code. I forgot I hadn't done that. Sorry. Checkout main again and git pull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257291/discussion-between-lotusms-and-jonas-beck).